# Passing an object from controller to form type

Tags: php, symfony

I want to pass an object from controller to my form builder so I can use it later on for my ChoiceType field. How do I accomplish that?

This is my controller:

```
    $choices          = [];
    $table2Repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SwipeBundle:Company');
    $table2Objects    = $table2Repository->findAll();

    foreach ($table2Objects as $table2Obj) {
        $choices[$table2Obj->getId()] = $table2Obj->getId() . ' - ' . $table2Obj->getName();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(SubAgentType::class, $choices, array(
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl('backend_sub_agent_create'),
        'method'=>'POST'
    ));
```

This is my SubAgentType.php

```
class SubAgentType extends AbstractType {

    protected $choices;

    public function __construct (Choices $choices)
    {
        $this->choices = $choices;
    }    

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('company_id', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'mapped'  => false,
            'choices' => $choices,
        ));
```

The problem is I get the error below.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyBundle\Form\SubAgentType::__construct() must be an instance of
>   MyBundle\Form\Choices,

Answer (score 0):

To respond to your question :

in your services.yml file :

```
myform.type:
    class: AppBundle\Form\MyFormType
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
    tags:
      - { name: form.type }
```

in your MyFormType :

```
/**
 * @var EntityManagerInterface
 */
protected $em;

/**
 * LicenseeType constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $choices          = [];
    $table2Repository = $this-em->getRepository('SwipeBundle:Company');
    $table2Objects    = $table2Repository->findAll();

    foreach ($table2Objects as $table2Obj) {
        $choices[$table2Obj->getId()] = $table2Obj->getId() . ' - ' . $table2Obj->getName();
    }

    ...
```

But, clearly, you don't need to do that if you correctly define your entities relations.

Comment: `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "myform.type"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to resolve your constructor in SubAgentType, $choices doesn't need to be a subtype of Choices:

```
public function __construct ($choices)
{
    $this->choices = $choices;
}
```

If you inject an array in your controller, then the constructor must accept an array.

Comment: but you should have another behavior, what is it now?